# Is this a power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Is the following a power series?
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_k \left( \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)^k \ , x \in (-1,1)$$
where $a_k$ is a bounded sequence.

I was asked to show that this power series converges, and that the sum function was continuous.

Two things confused me: Why are they calling this weird-looking thing a "power series"? And why are they asking for "convergence"? Isn't it customary to ask for either pointwise or uniform convergence, especially with the question of continuous sum function in mind?

Comment: That's not a power series.

Comment: I thought the same, but I figured that they are asking for convergence .... and we know that if a power series convergence on some interval, then its sum function is actually continuous, and that, I thought, would explain the vague question of "show convergence".

Comment: It is a power series in $2x/(1+x^2)$. And inasmuch as $a_n$ is bounded and $|x|<1$, which implies that $|y|=|2x/(1+x^2)|<1$, the series converges.

Comment: Did you mean to sum over $k$, not $n$?

Answer (score 3):

It's a power series in $u = \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$.

As such, if $|u| < 1$ for $x \in (-1, 1)$, then as long as $a_k$ is bounded, the series is convergent.

Fortunately, we can indeed show that $|u| < 1$.  When $0 \leq x < 1$,

$$
0 < (x-1)^2 \leq 1
$$
$$
0 < x^2-2x+1 \leq 1
$$
$$
-1-x^2 < -2x < -x^2
$$
$$
1+x^2 > 2x > x^2 \geq 0
$$
$$
0 \leq \frac{2x}{1+x^2} < 1
$$

Complete similar reasoning for $-1 < x \leq 0$, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been written as a power series in $x$, but it can be expressed as one.

Consider the term $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$. If we expand the geometric series here, we find
$$
\frac{2x}{1 + x^2} = 2x(1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots) = 2x - 2x^3 + 2x^5 - 2x^7 + \cdots
$$
which when raised to the $k$-th power gives you something of the form
$$
2^kx^k + O(x^{k+1})
$$
As such, you can expand this out and you will only find finitely many terms of that contribute to each coefficient of a power series in $x$; that is only the first $k$ terms in the expression will contribute to any coefficient $b_k$ of the resulting series $\sum_k b_kx^k$, and so it is well-defined---at least for $-1 < x < 1$.